# how to make tcpdump to display ip and port number but not hostname and protocol

Tags: linux, networking, tcpdump

I'm using tcpdump for some tests
I want to see the IP and port number 
but the output of tcpdump is like

```
IP pl1snu.koren.kr.http > kitch.pl.sophia.inria.fr.dnp: Flags [P.], seq 54:72, ack 1, win 5792, length 18
```

it only shows the hostname and the protocol
for http, it is easy to know it is 80
but for dnp I have to search

so is it possible to how to make tcpdump to display ip and port number but not hostname and protocol
if so , how?
thanks

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Add `-n` to your `tcpdump` command line.

From the [tcpdump manpage](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html):

```
-n Don't convert addresses (i.e., host addresses, port numbers, etc.) to names.
```

It should also be noted that on Fedora (and perhaps other derivatives: RHEL, CentOS, etc.) they have [patched](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/tcpdump/sources/patches) the original tcpdump version to include a separate option `-nn` to remove port numbers.  From the [manpage](http://linuxmanpages.net/manpages/fedora21/man8/tcpdump.8.html):

```
-n     Don't convert host addresses to names.   This  can  be  used  to
              avoid DNS lookups.

-nn    Don't convert protocol and port numbers etc. to names either.
```

Comment: port number is still converted to protocol name using `-n`

Comment: "port number is still converted to protocol name using -n"  Not with, for example, the tcpdump 4.1.1 that comes with OS X Mountain Lion or with tcpdump built from the top of the tcpdump.org Git trunk.  On what version of tcpdump are you seeing -n *not* suppress the conversion of port numbers to protocol names?

Answer (score 10):

I use `-nn` parameter.

> `-nn`: Don’t resolve hostnames or port names.

Run it as:

```
tcpdump -nn
```

Answer (score 2):

`-n` works only for hostnames, but doesn't work for port numbers. `-nn` does the trick for both. This is running tcpdump version 4.5.1 on Fedora 20 gnu/linux. Downvoted answer of @ATMc is the only correct. I sadly can neither upvote it nor write a comment below it because of low karma.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach is:

```
sudo tcpdump -ni any
```

Steps to test:

1. Open a console and type:

   ```
   sudo nc -l -p 6666
   ```
2. Open another console and type:

   ```
   sudo tcpdump -ni any
   ```

   If the output is too verbose you can filter it out (`| grep -v "patter1n|pattern2"`)
3. Open a third console and type:

   ```
   telnet localhost 6666
   ```

Expected output:

```
10:37:13.770997 IP 127.0.0.1.56920 > 127.0.0.1.443: Flags [S], seq 2822288041, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 1028779 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

If you use `sudo tcpdump -i any` you will see something like this:

```
10:38:22.106022 IP localhost.56924 > localhost.https: Flags [S], seq 3147104744, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 1045863 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

Comment: That's the same as the other answer - the `-i any` isn't necessary if you want to suppress address/port-to-name conversion, it's just the `-n` that matters.

Answer (score -1):

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -p -nn | grep "IP" | awk '{print$3 ,$4 ,$5}' | sed 's/://'
```

Comment: i do not get it

Comment: While the question says “display ip and port number but not hostname and protocol”, I doubt that it means “display ip and port number but not *any* of the other information”.   (I could be wrong, but nobody else seems to have interpreted the question the way you did.)   So your answer seems to boil down to two parts: (1) use `-nn` to display services like “http” and “dnp” as a port number instead of a name (which has been presented in three previous answers), and (2) use `awk` to throw away data on packet contents (which is probably not desired).

Comment: However it's exactly what I want.